# Is there an angular period?

Tags: angular-momentum, frequency

I was looking at Wikipedia’s page for angular frequency and it had a picture that had a cube with each vertex representing different frequencies and periods, however the angular period just said “?”. Is this just saying that the angular period doesn’t exist or that it hasn’t been discovered yet? [image]

Comment: I think that it might be a statement that there is no commonly used/agreed symbol for angular period?

Comment: $\uparrow T$-bar?

Comment: @Qmechanic It seems like there is a pattern when it comes to defined quantities that are divided by $2\pi$, and when the quantity is divided by that we "bar" it. Like angular wavelength, $\lambda$, and $h$ which becomes $\hbar$. It makes sense that we would call it T-bar, so why is that not universally accepted?

Comment: I suppose 'angular' period would have units $\mathrm{s / rad}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The comment by Farcher was posted while I was typing this answer, and I didn't see it until I was done.  Didn't mean to be repetitive.)

I think the question-mark simply means that there is no conventional symbol for that quantity. Based on the pattern illustrated by the cube, I infer that "angular period" would be defined as $T/(2\pi)$, where $T$ is the linear period. This is analogous to the definition of "angular frequency" as $\omega\equiv 2\pi f$, where $f$ is the linear frequency. The angular period could also be written in terms of the angular frequency as $1/\omega$ (this is the same as $T/(2\pi)$), just like the linear period $T$ is written in terms of the linear frequency $f$ as $T=1/f$.

Whereas angular frequency is a widely used term (commonly denoted $\omega$), "angular period" does not seem to be widely used. That doesn't mean that it's undiscovered (it's just a definition), only that people don't often express things that way.